# bottom navigation bar within navigation drawer

Tags: android, fragment, navigationbar

I'm in the process of building an app with this hierarchy:

- Home
- Data

  *data_1

  *data_2

  *data_3
- Bluetooth

For Home, data and bluetooth, they are fragments in the navigation drawer, while I would like to attach a bottom navigation bar within the "data" fragment only. There are two things I concerned/have questions on since so far I just saw cases with bottom navigation bar with navigation drawer are not nested:

- Does this mean I would need to inflate another 3 fragments within the "data" fragments?
- Are MainActivity variables still available for the fragments of "data_1, 2 and 3"? What is the best approach to communicate between the data_1 fragment and main activity?